# Film where a damaged ship can't count down sequentially during a self destruct

Tags: story-identification, movie, computers

I remember part of a film or maybe TV movie where a boy or maybe a teenager is in a spaceship. I think I saw it on TV in the 1980s, so it's either a 1970s film/movie or from the early 1980s.

The ship has an intelligent computer. Somehow the computer becomes damaged or faulty. It can no longer properly function but it still tries to do as requested, so when a self destruct is commenced the computer counts down. However, due to the damage the numbers are not in a decreasing sequence. Instead, they are jumbled up.
Finally the computer announces zero and the ship explodes.
I think the computer had a female voice.

What was this film or TV movie called?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Like what year you watched it? Any actors or the studios?

Comment: Was it broken or was it using a random number generator?

Comment: @Edlothiad I think I saw it on TV in the 1980s, so it's either a 1970s film/movie or from the early 1980s.

Comment: @Valorum it was broken.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the movie you are looking for is [Battle Beyond the Stars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080421/)

The ship you are referencing was the one flown by Richard Thomas' character Shad.
That ship had an AI/Computer called Nell.  At the end, during the final battle against the enemy the ship is damaged, and Shad sets Nell to self-destruct.  The countdown is what you remember (at about 1h 36 mins in the video below).

Comment: Thank you, yep that's the one. I searched for several hours last night and another hour or so this morning looking for it with no luck.

Comment: Drat I was working and couldn't get answer in in time lol.